# My index.html not in DocumentRoot

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd

My structure is this

```
cdn
- node_modules/
- build/
-- bower_components/
-- css/
-- templates/
-- sst/
--- index.html
```

How can I configure apache2/symlink/.htaccess to use www.app.com instead of www.app.com/build/sst/ in order to access index.html and maintain folder structure

My current setup is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /app/www/vhosts/www.app.no/cdn/
  ServerName www.app.no
  ServerAlias www.app.no js.www.app.no html.www.app.no css.www.app.no
  ServerAdmin noob@noob.com
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

  Include /etc/apache2/local.conf.d/app-restricted-access.conf

  ErrorLog /app/www/vhosts/www.app.no/logs/error_log
  CustomLog /app/www/vhosts/www.app.no/logs/access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your question is really incomprehensible. Please try to explain your problem better.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I'm doing my best :(

Comment: Much better. Now give it a better title.

Comment: Thx, also, I simply cannot think of better title that have meaning and less then 20 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried DirectoryIndex directive ?

```
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.txt  /app/www/vhosts/www.app.no/cdn/build/sst/index.html
```

from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html

(The drawback is  that it will use this index for all directory under www.app.no, unless they have a local `index.html` or `index.txt` )

Edit:

- `mod_dir` must be enabled, this can be achieved/check in the `LoadModules` directive.
- search for `LoadModule` in config file, you must have a line like

  LoadModule dir_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so

(with proper paths for /usr/lib/apache2/modules )